# JFrame Questions (deleting textimages adding new ones)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

So I am making a game, and I want to know if it is possible so when lets say "You created a fire" it **deletes** that line and then displays "Your fire turns into ashes".

two more,

I want to make a jframe background, and let's say I "login" the background disappears, and a new background comes in(but the game, not a background).

I want to add a image icon( already added) (IMAGE = FIRE) it **deletes** that image and a new one appears( IMAGE = ASHES), how can I do this?

```
public class FireLabel extends JPanel {
public LabelDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(3,1));  //3 rows, 1 column
    JLabel label1;

    //Create the first label.
    label1 = new JLabel("You created a Fire", JLabel.CENTER);

    //Add the labels.
    add(label1);
    add(label2);
    add(label3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The context is a little light, however.

For swicthing from one view to another, I would suggest using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which would allow you to change from the login screen to the game screen.

If you're using `JLabel` as you primary output...simple change the text or icon using `setText` or `setIcon` as required...

Answer (score 0):

1. To change that, use `JLabel.setText`. You will then have to call `validate` for the change to take effect.
2. I recommend swapping out the content pane for this. Put the login screen in a `JPanel` and set that as the content pane, then when needed, change the content pane to a second `JPanel` for the game.
3. Use the same technique as #1. Use a `JLabel` to display the image.